# Is there any way to skip unused libraries when linking?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, linker

I have a main.exe and two libraries (lib1 and lib2):

In main.exe:

```
extern void f3();

int main() {
    f3();
}
```

In lib1.cpp:

```
extern void f4();
void f2() {
    f4();
}

void f3() {
}
```

In lib2.cpp:

```
void f4() {
}
```

So theoretically, I only need lib1 to build main.exe successfully, because only `f3()` is called by `main()`.

However I found under both gcc and MSVC, I have to have lib2 as well, otherwise linker reports it can't find `f4()`.

I've tried linker flag `--as-needed` but it doesn't help. So my question is: is there any way (e.g. linker flags) that I can use to build main.exe successfully without lib2? Assume I can't modify any C++ source code.

Comment: The short answer is: no, there isn't.

Comment: Assuming your are linking static libs, when the linker links with lib1 and see's that it calls f4 it will try to link lib2.  I think you need both.

Comment: I think the object file format doesn't indicate all the dependencies, so it can't tell at link time that `f4` isn't reacable.

Comment: The Microsoft compiler has an option (`/Gy`) to package functions separately.  If you can recompile lib1 with this option, and link your program with the `/OPT:REF` linker option, this may eliminate the dependency lib1 has on lib2.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks for the suggestion. However I tried it but seems the same issue is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flag `--as-needed` doesn't work because the linker tries to resolve any undefined identifiers that exist in your object files.

Basically you must include an implementation of f4(). But for any reason you don't want to provide `lib2` to your linker, you can create a dummy `lib2` which contains your dummy implementation of `f4` (make a cpp file with an empty f4 function will do the trick).

For example:

```
gcc main.cpp lib1.o lib2_dummy.cpp -o main.exe
```

Comment: Thanks. It's actually the way I did to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can split lib1.cpp into two source modules, lib1a.cpp and lib1b.cpp, and include both of those in the lib1 library.  Then the linker will be able to import `f3` without importing `f2`, and so won't need lib2.

lib1a.cpp

```
extern void f4();
void f2() {
    f4();
}
```

lib1b.cpp

```
void f3() {
}
```

Comment: The question mensioned that "Assume I can't modify any C++ source code"